# Можно ли использовать чужие проекты для портфолио?

Tags: unity3d, github

Есть проект исходный код которого уже есть на github. Если конкретнее - Unity проект. Если я переделаю немного код и добавлю новые механики — будет ли это плохо? По идее, можно будет найти этот код через поиск кода на github. И вообще кто-то таким занимается?

Comment: Да, таким занимаются. Я часто заворачиваю код если могу показать что он не оригинальный. Иногда нужно понимать на что способен человек. Сам человек.

Comment: Но если вы укажете что это производная работа, которую вы взяли там-то и добавили в неё то-то, то в этом случае никаких проблем. Так делаются большинство проектов - всегда есть что-то предшествующее.

Comment: Чужие проекты для портфолио хороши, когда там получается собственный вклад в большой известный проект. И значек pull shark в профиле появится.

Comment: Если цели это обмануть, то  вопрос в том, кого обмануть. Даже без поиска по гиту, программист от мидла и выше в состоянии понять, что два разных куска, скорее всего, написаны разными людьми, обезличен разве что только "чистый код". Если работодатель крупный и тот кто собеседует, занимается этим давно, видел уже много проектов из гита выданных за свои, все хотят выбрать по лучше и вероятность, что показывают одни и те-же проекты есть.

Comment: Покажите. Заодно проверите, как там ревьювят присланный код. Спросят - скажете, не спросят - значит не интересовались. Если код отправите не в zip архиве а в виде репы на гитхабе, можно по истории коммитов посмотреть, как вы его писали. Если один большой коммит - у меня был бы вопрос: вы не умеете пользоваться гитом? А раскидать чужой код по коммитам и подделать кипучую деятельность трудно. Но можно авторов коммитов переписать. Тогда если найдут - точно будет выглядеть как воровство.